# Using a foreach loop in a Doctrine arraycollection

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I have just discovered the following library https://github.com/simshaun/recurr and the output of is using a Doctrine `arrayCollection`.

How can I use a `foreach` loop to loop through this array and get the date value?

```
Array
 (
    [0] => Recurr\Recurrence Object
        (
        [start:protected] => DateTime Object
            (
                [date] => 2014-08-03 15:00:00.000000
                [timezone_type] => 3
                [timezone] => America/Vancouver
            )

        [end:protected] => DateTime Object
            (
                [date] => 2014-08-03 17:00:00.000000
                [timezone_type] => 3
                [timezone] => America/Vancouver
            )

    )

[1] => Recurr\Recurrence Object
    (
        [start:protected] => DateTime Object
            (
                [date] => 2014-08-04 15:00:00.000000
                [timezone_type] => 3
                [timezone] => America/Vancouver
            )

        [end:protected] => DateTime Object
            (
                [date] => 2014-08-04 17:00:00.000000
                [timezone_type] => 3
                [timezone] => America/Vancouver
            )

    )

  )
```

Comment: Please, be more specific: what do you want to do here?

Comment: Apologies, updated my question. I am trying to get the date value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will not work in this context - you can use a foreach loop to get through the elements, but you are not allowed to access the property of the object, because it's marked as protected. So you'll use a Getter that you can access it.

```
foreach (<yourarray> as $numObject => $object)
{
    $object->end;  // So you could access it, but its protected
    $object->getEndDate();  // Like this you can access it
}
```

And if you have it, than you have a simple \DateTime Object and with the [format method](http://php.net/manual/de/datetime.format.php) you can get your date string e.g. `$object->getEndDate()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');`.

Comment: Hey andreashager, I believe I understand exactly what you are saying. I've tried and for some reason I get the following error "Call to undefined method Recurr\Recurrence::getEndDate() i"

Comment: Small typo.. thanks for your help.. print_r($object->getStart()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')); was what I needed.